# How to place 2 cols' elements to the right and the 3rd to the left using Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, forms, bootstrap-4

I've tried so many, but my lack of HTML and Bootstrap didn't allow for success, so I have to come after you - the experts!

This is how this `form` looks VS the Expected:
[image]

```
<div id='form-horizontal'>
  <div class="row justify-content-around space-evenly" id="selectFieldsDiv">
    <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
      <label for="agencySelect">Choose</label>
      <select id="agencySelect" onchange="loadClientsFromSS(selectedAgency())">
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
      <label for="clientSelect">Choose</label>
      <select id="clientSelect" onchange="loadClientTasks(selectedClient())">
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-end">
      <div id="addTaskBtnSpot"></div>
      <div id="cancelTaskBtnSpot"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Appreciate your help - as usual!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add your columns on your own by dividing the div to 8 by 4.In 8 grid you can add your choose dropdowns by 4 by 4 division and in 4 grid you can add your 2 by 2 division
Let me know if it's work if not ping me up I'll provide you other solution as well

Comment: Hey! Sorry I'm a newbe here and I can't really wrap my head around it without any further direction. Sorry if it's too much to ask and this is actually a pattern where both questions and answers should contain examples of code - therefore, could there be a quick example of your explanation above? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks!